# How can i add javascript tag file to Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new with Vue but i try to import JS script tag to Vue but it's not working, please help me and thank you for answer...............

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="bg">
      <div class="overlay-bg"></div>
      <div class="project-img project-6"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay-swipe">
      <div class="over-1"></div>
      <div class="over-2"></div>
      <div class="over-3"></div>
      <div class="over-4"></div>
      <div class="over-5"></div>

      <div class="over-1-border"></div>
      <div class="over-2-border"></div>
      <div class="over-3-border"></div>
      <div class="over-4-border"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script src="assets/homepage/js/plugin.js"></script>
<script src="assets/homepage/js/fullsreen-showcase.js"></script>
<script src="assets/homepage/js/main.js"></script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import "../assets/homepage/awsome/font-awesome-5/css/fontawesome-all.min.css";
  @import "../assets/homepage/css/main.css";
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do either one of the following:

```vue
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- the template -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import "assets/homepage/js/plugin.js";
  import "assets/homepage/js/fullsreen-showcase.js";
  import "assets/homepage/js/main.js";

  // Or if those files are modules
  // import Something from "assets/homepage/js/plugin.js";
  // ...

  export default {
    // ...
  }
</script>
```

Or:

```vue
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- the template -->
  </div>
</template>

<script src="assets/homepage/js/main.js"></script>
```

#### main.js

Import the rest of the JS files, considering `main.js` as the entry point.

```js
import "assets/homepage/js/plugin.js";
import "assets/homepage/js/fullsreen-showcase.js";

export default {
  // ...
}
```